# How to close FTPClient FileStream properly

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I'm reading the content from a file located on a server with the FTPClient from Apache Commons Net. It works fine when only reading once. But when I'm trying to read a second file, the InputStream of my FTPClient returns null. This is my code:

```
            FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
            ftpClient.connect("myhostname");
            ftpClient.login("myusername", "mypassword");

            // read InputStream from file
            InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream("/my/firstfile.txt");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            // read every line...

            // close everything
            inputStream.close();
            bufferedReader.close();


            // second try
            inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream("/my/secondfile.txt");
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            // ...
            inputStream.close();
            bufferedReader.close();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

After closing the `InputStream`, do the following:

```
ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
```

You can find more information in the [javadoc of FTPClient#retrieveFileStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#retrieveFileStream(java.lang.String)):

> To finalize the file transfer you must call completePendingCommand and check its return value to verify success. If this is not done, subsequent commands may behave unexpectedly.